# Tried to custom the shorten linked (bit.ly) via api but it keep return me 406

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, bit.ly, http-status-code-406

As stated, I tried to customize the link (back-half). It keep return me 406. Or should I use Post/custom_bitlinks instead?

Here is my current code:

```
function bitlyori (i, title){
var form = {
    "group_guid": "MINE",  
    "domain": "bit.ly",  
    "long_url": i,
    "title" : title
    }; 
const MY_TOKEN = "MINE";
const option = {
  headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${MY_TOKEN}` },
  method: 'post',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  payload: JSON.stringify(form),
  };
var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4/bitlinks', option);
return (JSON.parse(result.getContentText()));
}

function bitly(url,title,custom) {
var temp = bitlyori(url, title);
var form_2 = { 
  "custom_bitlinks": [custom] ,
    };
const MY_TOKEN = "MINE";
const option_2 = {
  headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${MY_TOKEN}` },
  method: 'patch',
  payload: form_2}; 
var temp_link = 'https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4/bitlinks/'+ temp["id"];
var result_2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(temp_link, option_2);
return (JSON.parse(result_2.getContentText()));
}
```

P.S. here is the reference: https://dev.bitly.com/api-reference#updateCustomBitlink

---

**UPDATE**: Somehow made it through the success one; yet wasn't able to patch anything to the original. Here is the part that I fixed it.

```
function bitly(url,title2,custom) {
var temp = bitlyori(url, title2);
var form_2 = { 
  "custom_bitlinks": [custom]
  //"bitlink_id": temp["id"]
    };
const MY_TOKEN = "MINE";
const option_2 = {
  headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${MY_TOKEN}`},
  method: 'patch',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  payload: JSON.stringify(form_2),
  muteHttpExceptions: true
  }; 
var temp_link = 'https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4/bitlinks/'+temp["id"];
//return (temp_link);
var result_2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(temp_link, option_2);
var CusAr = result_2.getContentText();
return (CusAr);}
```

Comment: Not sure if there is any other problem in your request, but judging from the API [documentation link you provided](https://dev.bitly.com/api-reference#updateCustomBitlink), the URL should include `/custom_bitlinks` instead of `/bitlinks`: `https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4/custom_bitlinks/...`.

Comment: Also, are you sure `temp["id"]` is getting populated correctly and refers to an existing bitlink?

Comment: Thank you so much! Still it did not work yet. I somehow made it to return 200 successfully; yet, json.stringify was not patched to the original one.

Comment: 406 or 404?`````````````````​`````````````````

Comment: oh sorry it was 404 and then I tried again it turned to 406.

Comment: Is there still a question? Also, to  notify us, use `@` like @TheMaster

Comment: Also [search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script+http-status-code-406) the tags

Comment: @TheMaster I did get 200 HTTP response finally, also I tried the other fields apart from the "custom_bitlinks" which is still problematic, it could be patched successfully. Is this because the customs_bitlinks required the arrays of string as an input?

Comment: I've never seen documentation as lacking as that from bit.ly. You would think in 15 years they could manage to produce documentation that was at least meaningful.